# Web UI Framework for Configuration

Tags: java, configuration, user-interface, frameworks, jmx

I am looking for a UI Framework that supports the following features:

- Integrated with Apache Commons Config and/or JFig
- Supports nested tabs
- Understands users/groups/roles
- Can interact with JMX MBeans
- Doesn't require Javascript in order to function
- Written in Java and ideally JSP-based

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt you can find anything like that, as you specify both browser-end, server-end and development-end requirements. It quite limits the field.

I think you won't find a single framework which supports those requiremens out of the box.

If the GUI is important to you, I'd recommend Wicket. The nested tabs and no-javascript-*required* are supported just fine (at least when I used it last year). This is totally not compatible with JSP though...

As a security system Spring Security (formerly Acegi) leaps to mind. It can be integrated with almost anything - if there isn't already a binding available.

The "Can interact with JMX MBeans"  needs some clarification - what should it do with those beans?

If you're not working on a Mac you could also consider GWT (the GWT development environment doesn't really work with 64 bit java). It's fully java, the front-end gets compiled.

And integration with Commons Config / JFig? What do you wish to have configured? Even if the framework supports commons config it probably wouldn't allow you to configure what you want configured...

I personally am currently using spring MVC with spring security. I chose this because we already were using Spring, and I like JSP as the view technology as long as the views are simple.

If I had a requirement to create javascript and javascript-less pages with the same code, I'd have chosen Wicket so this flexibility would not be *my* problem.

I realize this is not an aswer to the question, so good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Neither a UI nor works with JMX but does what JFig does without the XML bloat and is fully Java (uses Commons Configuration, Commons IO, Guava etc).

The Maven configuration has good defaults  but has lots of additional options for fitting to legacy environments. Can build scripts as well as configuration.

Coupled with the Maven Assembly plugin we use it for continuous delivery pushing auto-deploy scripts pushing properties/configuration, (liquibase) database changes, application server CLI and web server changes.

Latest version on Maven Central is 0.9.10:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.ariht</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-generation-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.10</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
           <goals>
               <goal>generate/goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

https://github.com/sofdes/config-generation-maven-plugin